# How to "Factory reset" virtual device in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to imitate a factory reset in Android Studio AVDs so I would land on FRP Lock on the boot?
Theorically it should be possible since we have all the .Img files inside, but which ones to edit/delete?

Comment: If you mean is ```wipe data```, you can do that from actions menu of AVD

Comment: Probably easiest to just delete the AVD and create a new one

Comment: Guys.. wiping all data or deleting and adding new avd would cause all data to be lost, meaning, the FRP lock would be gone too.